# Snaking columns with even height rows issue

Tags: html, css

I have some css html that I have been asked to make a snaking column of labels / values but if one of the values on the left is 2 lines the one on the right should be equal height.

I can only get this to work if the outer container has height set. I want this to just be auto-height.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  <style>     
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .row {
            flex: 1 0 14rem;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }


        .column {
            flex: 1;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque labore fuga iste, ut nam quod voluptates vel! Ex est obcaecati itaque architecto totam, sapiente aliquam veniam repudiandae assumenda. Provident, nostrum? Officiis expedita,
                repudiandae dignissimos veniam sit architecto voluptate nam est earum? Fugiat natus exercitationem hic at, iusto dolore soluta distinctio illo voluptates ratione? Distinctio, veniam deserunt libero aspernatur optio obcaecati. Unde est
                doloribus iste aut quod perspiciatis, fugit necessitatibus magni animi excepturi eaque dolor sequi, ipsa rem ipsam maiores facilis dignissimos nam. Voluptate cum quo eius. Impedit quisquam optio vero! Voluptatem magni, nisi quo consequuntur
                itaque totam quia voluptate repellendus alias? Laboriosam possimus unde debitis facere numquam asperiores dolor aliquam amet nam, totam quaerat voluptate modi libero maiores, similique magni. Ipsam cupiditate autem est aliquam, magnam
                quasi perspiciatis minus consequatur alias dolor quibusdam, distinctio, adipisci facere impedit minima necessitatibus. Reiciendis ducimus corrupti, ab quis mollitia aspernatur cum dignissimos deleniti incidunt.</div>
            <div class="column">2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel debitis voluptas fugiat vero dolorum consequuntur ullam magnam perspiciatis, veniam culpa, quos ex voluptatem. Vitae officiis eius illo doloremque natus quas. Quis neque id repudiandae
                ut sunt! Voluptate eligendi odio placeat enim quod laudantium! Dolorem velit sapiente dolorum vero? Iusto ad nam commodi voluptatem? Distinctio quas voluptate alias quo consectetur laboriosam. Nam beatae suscipit architecto quaerat id
                esse sit, aliquid consectetur enim expedita. Rem obcaecati ducimus cupiditate expedita illo perspiciatis, itaque ipsam ipsa placeat delectus excepturi corrupti dicta non voluptas ex. Ea sint dignissimos itaque ducimus adipisci nemo debitis
                totam culpa laudantium. Molestias ipsum eaque temporibus odio excepturi, libero ipsam vero sequi voluptate quis repudiandae quod corporis. Repellat commodi saepe omnis!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">3) Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae vel aspernatur sequi facilis earum assumenda dolorem molestiae sunt, numquam autem. Maiores ullam odit quae velit ex? Iusto enim dicta voluptates. Alias excepturi vero
                voluptatibus, saepe error iusto laudantium illo nemo veritatis iure quidem. Maxime cum eveniet nihil voluptas odio obcaecati, accusamus voluptate sed autem? Illo adipisci dignissimos esse reprehenderit labore.</div>
            <div class="column">4) Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab ducimus blanditiis similique saepe necessitatibus placeat, expedita ratione quisquam consequatur a dicta exercitationem molestias, neque, error totam reiciendis veritatis vitae
                nihil!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is an example of what I want it to look like
[image: snaking columns with equal height in each row]

Comment: Use CSS-Grid which does this an easier way by default.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CSS-Grid and create a 2-column grid by using `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`. Then you do not need sub-containers to create the different rows. The cards by default will have the same height as the largest element in the row:

```css
.container {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, auto) / repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2rem; 
}

.card {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque labore fuga iste, ut nam quod voluptates vel! Ex est obcaecati itaque architecto totam, sapiente aliquam veniam repudiandae assumenda. Provident, nostrum? Officiis expedita,
                repudiandae dignissimos veniam sit architecto voluptate nam est earum? Fugiat natus exercitationem hic at, iusto dolore soluta distinctio illo voluptates ratione? Distinctio, veniam deserunt libero aspernatur optio obcaecati. Unde est
                doloribus iste aut quod perspiciatis, fugit necessitatibus magni animi excepturi eaque dolor sequi, ipsa rem ipsam maiores facilis dignissimos nam. Voluptate cum quo eius. Impedit quisquam optio vero! Voluptatem magni, nisi quo consequuntur
                itaque totam quia voluptate repellendus alias? Laboriosam possimus unde debitis facere numquam asperiores dolor aliquam amet nam, totam quaerat voluptate modi libero maiores, similique magni. Ipsam cupiditate autem est aliquam, magnam
                quasi perspiciatis minus consequatur alias dolor quibusdam, distinctio, adipisci facere impedit minima necessitatibus. Reiciendis ducimus corrupti, ab quis mollitia aspernatur cum dignissimos deleniti incidunt.</div>
  <div class="card">2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel debitis voluptas fugiat vero dolorum consequuntur ullam magnam perspiciatis, veniam culpa, quos ex voluptatem. Vitae officiis eius illo doloremque natus quas. Quis neque id repudiandae
                ut sunt! Voluptate eligendi odio placeat enim quod laudantium! Dolorem velit sapiente dolorum vero? Iusto ad nam commodi voluptatem? Distinctio quas voluptate alias quo consectetur laboriosam. Nam beatae suscipit architecto quaerat id
                esse sit, aliquid consectetur enim expedita. Rem obcaecati ducimus cupiditate expedita illo perspiciatis, itaque ipsam ipsa placeat delectus excepturi corrupti dicta non voluptas ex. Ea sint dignissimos itaque ducimus adipisci nemo debitis
                totam culpa laudantium. Molestias ipsum eaque temporibus odio excepturi, libero ipsam vero sequi voluptate quis repudiandae quod corporis. Repellat commodi saepe omnis!</div>
  <div class="card">3) Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae vel aspernatur sequi facilis earum assumenda dolorem molestiae sunt, numquam autem. Maiores ullam odit quae velit ex? Iusto enim dicta voluptates. Alias excepturi vero
                voluptatibus, saepe error iusto laudantium illo nemo veritatis iure quidem. Maxime cum eveniet nihil voluptas odio obcaecati, accusamus voluptate sed autem? Illo adipisci dignissimos esse reprehenderit labore.</div>
  <div class="card">4) Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab ducimus blanditiis similique saepe necessitatibus placeat, expedita ratione quisquam consequatur a dicta exercitationem molestias, neque, error totam reiciendis veritatis vitae
                nihil!
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I am not too familiar with grid